# Run a cron in just one node of my server

Tags: java, cron, cron-task

I have 2 nodes runing on my server in balance load and I have a cron, but I just want it to work on one node of my server, Is there any way I can do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just schedule it on a single server? E.g. you have ServerA and ServerB, just add the crontab entry to ServerA?

Is it actually a cron job, or are you using something like Quartz?